# Java apache pdfbox adding an External Font in a Pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I am looking for a way to embedd an external Font to use in on a PDF page (other fonts which are not available by default) in Java Apache PdfBox. Does someone know how to do it.

Comment: Please improve your question. Just adding a font is very easy (`document.getPage(0).getResources().add(PDType0Font.load(document,new File("....."))`) but this would not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

They have a way to use external fonts as described at 
Ref - https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html :

> ...PDFBox will load Resources/PDFBox_External_Fonts.properties off of the classpath to map font names to TTF font files. The UNKNOWN_FONT property in that file will tell PDFBox which font to use when no mapping exists.

If you could share the specific issue/error you ran into, if you did, I can offer a better actionable-response.